# How does SciKit Learn QuantileTransformer work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, correlation, quantile

I'm looking into the QuantileTransformer object in the Scikit-Learn Python library, in an attempt to "uniformize" residuals from an ARIMA model as part of a copula model. The idea is to feed my Kendall correlation matrix of residuals into a Student's t copula, and then apply the reverse transformation of the simulated residuals, in order to get values that are on the scale of the original data.

My question is this: What underlies this mechanism? I'm struggling to understand how the QuantileTransformer uniformizes values without knowledge of the true distribution. How does this happen without a percentile point function (PPF)? Or is there an assumed PPF that is simply not stated in the documentation ([here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.QuantileTransformer.fit))?

Comment: The quantile transformer seems to only transform data to match a gaussian or uniform distribution. And so doesn't know the true distribution. This describes some details, does it help? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-transformer

Comment: @bogovicj Thank you for this. I was just wondering how it can uniformize data without knowing the true distribution. Don't you need to know the CDF to do that?

Comment: I expect it uses the empirical CDF.